# Can I use both init() and initial value in Decoder?

Tags: ios, swift

I have lots of values in my codable struct. I have URLs coming in as ""(empty string) so I need custom Decoder to convert "" as nil. So I made a propertyWrapper to solve this.

For example, I have values like `["https://google.com", "", "https://google.com"]` and I want to make it as [URL?]. This works well with my decoder. It's converted as `[URL("https://google.com"), nil, URL("https://google.com")]`

However, I found a problem that, when I use `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`, I also have to initialize all other values in struct. Is there any way to use just `courseImages` and use other values in struct as set?

```
struct CabinetCourse: Codable {
  let courseId: String
  let title: String
  let planStartDate: Date
  let planEndDate: Date
  let companionTypeCd: String
  let courseCategory: String
  let planId: String
  let nickname: String?
  let isCabinet: Bool
  let isFavorite: Bool?
  let course: String
  let score: String
  let shareCnt: Int
  let favoriteCnt: Int
  let cabinetCnt: Int
  let placeCount: Int
  let createDt: Date
  let childPlaceCount: Int
  let wheelChairPlaceCount: Int
  let elderPlaceCount: Int
  @OptionalObject
  var courseImages: [URL?]


  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let emptyURLS = try values.decode([OptionalObject<URL>].self, forKey: .courseImages)
    courseImages = emptyURLS.map { $0.wrappedValue }

    // => these are the lines I don't want to write
    courseId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .courseId)
    title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
    planStartDate = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .planStartDate)
    planEndDate = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .planEndDate)
    companionTypeCd = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .companionTypeCd)
    courseCategory = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .courseCategory)
    planId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .planId)
    nickname = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .nickname)
    isCabinet = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isCabinet)
    isFavorite = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isCabinet)
    course = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .isCabinet)
    score = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .isCabinet)
  }



@propertyWrapper
struct OptionalObject<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
  var wrappedValue: Base?

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    do {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
      wrappedValue = try container.decode(Base.self)
    } catch {
      wrappedValue = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that some elements in the JSON array could be `""`, and you want those to become `nil`? Or do you mean the whole JSON array could be replaced with an empty string? In the latter case, you should use `[URL]?` as the type.

Comment: @Sweeper I have values like ["https://google.com", "", "https://google.com"] and I want to make it as [URL?]. This works well with my decoder. I just want to remove unnecessary lines. I'll fix my question to be obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding property wrappers. They "decorate" the entire property type - `[URL?]`, not just the array element type `URL?`. `[URL?]` doesn't match the type of `wrappedValue`. `[URL]?` does (`Base == [URL]`), but that's not what you want.

One way to create a property wrapper that can be applied to an array of optionals is:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct OptionalArray<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: [Base?]
    ...
```

Now `Base == URL` matches `[URL?]`, and in `init`, you have to decode a `[Base?]`:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var arr = [Base?]()
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    for _ in 0..<(container.count ?? 0) {
        if let element = try? container.decode(Base.self) {
            arr.append(element)
        } else {
            arr.append(nil)
            _ = try container.decode(String.self) // advances the decoder to the next position
        }
    }
    wrappedValue = arr
}
```

Once you have the property wrapper, you don't need the custom decoding code at all. Swift figures it out.

```
struct CabinetCourse: Decodable {
  let courseId: String
  let title: String
  let planStartDate: Date
  let planEndDate: Date
  let companionTypeCd: String
  let courseCategory: String
  let planId: String
  let nickname: String?
  let isCabinet: Bool
  let isFavorite: Bool?
  let course: String
  let score: String
  let shareCnt: Int
  let favoriteCnt: Int
  let cabinetCnt: Int
  let placeCount: Int
  let createDt: Date
  let childPlaceCount: Int
  let wheelChairPlaceCount: Int
  let elderPlaceCount: Int
  @OptionalArray
  var courseImages: [URL?]
}
// That's it!
```

For the encoding part, it depends on how you want to encode the `nil`s. But either way, the code is very similar to the decoding code.

Comment: I have one more question, When I have no value in courseImages, I get`KeyNotFound` error.. can you help me solve this?

Comment: Do you mean `courseImages` is an empty JSON array? @jonye._.jin

Comment: This is for another property wrapper. I made @OptionalValue property wrapper for `@OptionalValue var rpsntImageUrl: URL?` and when JSON doesn't have key `rpsntImageUrl`, it throws `"No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"rpsntImageUrl\", intValue: nil)`.. I thought URL? type would make no key error safe but it didn't.

Comment: ```
@propertyWrapper
struct OptionalValue<T: Codable>: Codable {
  var wrappedValue: T?

  init(from decoder: Decoder) {
    guard let container = try? decoder.singleValueContainer() else {
      wrappedValue = nil
      return
    }
    if let element = try? container.decode(T.self) {
      wrappedValue = element
    } else {
      wrappedValue = nil
    }
  }
}
```
this is my wrapper. Thanks in advance

Comment: @jonye._.jin Oh then you should probably ask another question, since it is unrelated to this one (check for duplicates first!) Anyway, I don't think you need a property wrapper for this. Properties of optional types will automatically be set to nil if they are not found in the JSON. This is the default behaviour. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Thats what I thought too!! However when key is not found It makes `keyNotFound` errors... :( I looked it up but couldn't find anything helpful, but thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67542958/property-wrapper-throws-keynotfound-error-when-key-is-missing-swift I had my question posted. Can you take a look? Thanks